# Работа с медиаплеером win 11 через python

Tags: python, windows, windows-11

Пытаюсь написать программу для работы с медиаплеером винды, написал такой код:

```
import os
query = input()
if query in ['музыка', 'включи музыку']:
    os.system('start mediaplayer.exe')
    keyboard.send("pause")
```

но при запуске кода он только плеер открывает, может есть какой-нибудь список команд с клавиатуры, или подскажите пожалуйста способ с помощью которого можно плеером управлять.

Comment: Наводите в медиа плеере на кнопку и показывается сочетание клавиш.

Comment: И как дальше с ними работать? Я попробовал засунуть вместо pause, но теперь он открывает плеер, и выбирает рандомный трек, при этом не нажимая паузу.

Comment: `keyboard.send('ctrl+p')` вот так к примеру

Comment: Говорю же, он просто случайный трек выбирает не проигрывая его

Comment: `time.sleep(3)` добавьте после `os.system('start mediaplayer.exe')` импортировав `time`

Comment: Всё равно он выбирает случайный трек и молчит, а также после этого он ctrl держит

Comment: Поставь английский язык и попробуй

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало, а можно как-то функциональные клавиши в пайсон использоваить?

Comment: Можно как-то fn вписать туда что-ли, может я пишу не так? ```keyboard.send("fn+F7")```

Comment: fn не используется os только клавиатурой т.е. данные о том что она нажата даже клавиатурой не отправляются.